# What wrong in my spring security configuraion?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spelevaluationexception

I am getting  exception while running my spring security

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'ROLE_USER' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
   <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<!-- <http>
<intercept-url pattern ="/welcome*" access="ROLE-USER"/>
<http-basic/>
</http> -->

<http>
<intercept-url pattern ="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
<form-login/>
<logout logout-success-url="/home"/>
</http>
<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
<user-service>
<user name="rahul" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
<user name="rohit" password="567" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
</user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springtraining.security.controller"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

LoginController

```
package com.springtraining.security.controller;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController
{
    public LoginController()
    {
        System.out.println("LoginController constructor is called ");
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model,Principal principal)
    {
        System.out.println("**********Login Controller is Called********");

        String name= principal.getName();
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security Custom Form Example");
        return "hello";
    }
@RequestMapping(value="/*",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap model)
{       
    return "home";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model)
{
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(ModelMap model)
{
    return "test";
}
}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Welcome To Spring Security </h3>
<a href="/SpringSecurity1-FORM/welcome"><b>Click here to logon</b></a>

</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Message : ${message}</h3>
<h3>Username : ${username}</h3>
<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />" >Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"`.

Comment: Thanks Attila ,It works :)

Comment: Hello Attila Gynongyosi,I have posted one more question regarding spring security can you help me out in that case as well !..